# Xcode - thick border appearing around the colors in attribute inspector

Tags: xcode, xcode9

In Xcode, there is a thick border around all the colors that appear in the attribute inspector. I don't think that I changed any setting. I am running Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

[image]

[image]

I also see a thick border around the selected screen object.

[image]

Comment: This is an Xcode bug; try to restart it.

Comment: I feel silly, It worked, Thanks